# SHA-1 Hash from a namespace Identifier in c/c++

Tags: hash, sha1

Suppose I have value of 01010101 and it's canonical sequence of octets:

0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31

Now i need to concatenate with namespace identifier value which is hexa-representation.

Then I need to find the value like

```
sha1 (0x03 0xfb 0xac 0xfc 0x73 0x8a 0xef 0x46 0x91 0xb1 0xe5 0xeb 0xee 0xab 0xa4 0xfe 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x31) = 
0xA8 0x82 0x16 0x4B 0x68 0xF9 0x01 0xE7 0x03 0xFC 0x7C 0x67 0x41 0xDC 0x66 0x97 0xB8 0xA1 0xA9 0x3E
```

After that how to ..
4b1682a8-f968-5701-83fc-7c6741dc6697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone my problem is solved when i follow rfc4122 link

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

There need some modification also in code.If anyone have same problem just ask me..

Thanks